# sudo crashes terminal but works from within a .sh file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sudo

**UPDATE 24/12/2021**

I had to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> out of the accecpted answers find and grep code to try and find the culprit half way in order to restart due to something else but I will update this post once I've found the root problem.

However, the accepted answer's redefine sudo code was used by me to fix the issue and I can sudo away without crashing!

So, for anyone else that may have the issue before I find the source problem here is what I did:

**.bashrc**

A the bottom of my .bashrc file

```bsh
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683619/344030
if [ -f ~/.sudo-fix ]; then
    source ~/.sudo-fix
else
  echo ' Unable to find ~/.sudo-fix so sudo may break again. look in Dropbox/Projects/hplaptop/sudo-broken/.sudo-fix for file to copy to home'
fi
```

**.sudo-fix**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#
# hplaptop fix only - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683619/344030
#

# Redefine sudo to reuse the last command if no args
sudo() {
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]
    then command sudo "$@"
    else command sudo "${BASH:-bash}" -c "$(history -p '!!')"
    fi
}
```

Thank you @roaima

**UPDATE 23/12/2021**

From some of the questions from the comments:

**Can I log in as root?:**

I can and have done, as it's Ubuntu the root user is disabled, but I was able to in my `test.sh` add `sudo passwd root` and gave myself a password.

Then once this is all fixed I will disable it again with `sudo passwd -l root` either in the terminal directly as the problem will be fixed or again in `test.sh` if I have to stick with this odd workaround.

**Does sudo date also trigger this?**

Yes `sudo date` also triggers the issue, Any sudo command does it unless as I say the sudo command is in a .sh and called.

**Difference between bash and sh**

Changing the shebang in my test.sh file makes no difference. It still works.

```
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
```

**Shell Info**

```
echo "$SHELL"
/bin/bash
```

**Please add the result of running `type sudo` to your question**

This wasn't what I was expecting, to be fair.

```bsh
type sudo
sudo is a function
sudo () 
{ 
    if [ "$1" ]; then
        sudo $@;
    else
        sudo "$BASH" -c "$(history -p !!)";
    fi
}
```

As this wasnt't what I was expecting I ran the following to see if that sudo function was in a file somewhere but it was only in the markdown file that is this post.

I also ran which sudo

```bsh
rg -l -F 'sudo ()'
Dropbox/Projects/hplaptop/sudo-broken/readme.md

which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
```

**strace sudo**

In the original question I mention `strace sudo` so for completeness here it is

```bsh
strace sudo
execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["sudo"], 0x7ffff0ccfa10 /* 74 vars */) = 0
access("/etc/suid-debug", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55fb4fd7e000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffe69316ac0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
fcntl(0, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(2, F_GETFD)                       = 0
access("/etc/suid-debug", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/haswell/x86_64/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/sudo/tls/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffe69315d10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/haswell/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/sudo/tls/haswell", 0x7ffe69315d10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/x86_64/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/sudo/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe69315d10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/tls/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/sudo/tls", 0x7ffe69315d10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/haswell/x86_64/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/sudo/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffe69315d10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/haswell/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/sudo/haswell", 0x7ffe69315d10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/x86_64/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/sudo/x86_64", 0x7ffe69315d10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/sudo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=142209, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 142209, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea9e9000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3407\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=133200, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2bea9e7000
mmap(NULL, 176296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea9bb000
mprotect(0x7f2bea9be000, 118784, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2bea9be000, 32768, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f2bea9be000
mmap(0x7f2bea9c6000, 81920, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xb000) = 0x7f2bea9c6000
mmap(0x7f2bea9db000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1f000) = 0x7f2bea9db000
mmap(0x7f2bea9dd000, 37032, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2bea9dd000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@p\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=163200, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 174600, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea990000
mprotect(0x7f2bea996000, 135168, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2bea996000, 102400, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f2bea996000
mmap(0x7f2bea9af000, 28672, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1f000) = 0x7f2bea9af000
mmap(0x7f2bea9b7000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7f2bea9b7000
mmap(0x7f2bea9b9000, 6664, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2bea9b9000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\23\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14848, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 16656, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea98b000
mmap(0x7f2bea98c000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f2bea98c000
mmap(0x7f2bea98d000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f2bea98d000
mmap(0x7f2bea98e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f2bea98e000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@[\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=105312, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 108824, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea970000
mmap(0x7f2bea975000, 61440, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7f2bea975000
mmap(0x7f2bea984000, 20480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x7f2bea984000
mmap(0x7f2bea989000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f2bea989000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/sudo/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360q\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029224, ...}) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
mmap(NULL, 2036952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea77e000
mprotect(0x7f2bea7a3000, 1847296, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2bea7a3000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7f2bea7a3000
mmap(0x7f2bea91b000, 303104, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19d000) = 0x7f2bea91b000
mmap(0x7f2bea966000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f2bea966000
mmap(0x7f2bea96c000, 13528, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2bea96c000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220$\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=27064, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 28984, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea776000
mmap(0x7f2bea778000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f2bea778000
mmap(0x7f2bea77b000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7f2bea77b000
mmap(0x7f2bea77c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7f2bea77c000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=584392, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2bea774000
mmap(NULL, 586536, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea6e4000
mmap(0x7f2bea6e6000, 409600, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f2bea6e6000
mmap(0x7f2bea74a000, 163840, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x66000) = 0x7f2bea74a000
mmap(0x7f2bea772000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8d000) = 0x7f2bea772000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \22\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18816, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 20752, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea6de000
mmap(0x7f2bea6df000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f2bea6df000
mmap(0x7f2bea6e1000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f2bea6e1000
mmap(0x7f2bea6e2000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f2bea6e2000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\201\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\345Ga\367\265T\320\374\301V)Yf]\223\337"..., 68, 824) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=157224, ...}) = 0
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\345Ga\367\265T\320\374\301V)Yf]\223\337"..., 68, 824) = 68
mmap(NULL, 140408, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea6bb000
mmap(0x7f2bea6c2000, 69632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x7f2bea6c2000
mmap(0x7f2bea6d3000, 20480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f2bea6d3000
mmap(0x7f2bea6d8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x7f2bea6d8000
mmap(0x7f2bea6da000, 13432, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2bea6da000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2bea6b9000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f2bea6b9c80) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2bea966000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2bea6d8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2bea6e2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2bea772000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2bea77c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2bea989000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2bea98e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2bea9b7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2bea9db000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55fb4fcaa000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2beaa39000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f2bea9e9000, 142209)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f2bea6b9f50)         = 321158
set_robust_list(0x7f2bea6b9f60, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f2bea6c2bf0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f2bea6d03c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f2bea6c2c90, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f2bea6d03c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ffe69316a10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffe69316a10)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55fb4fd7e000
brk(0x55fb4fd9f000)                     = 0x55fb4fd9f000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\ttmpfs\nnodev\tbd"..., 1024) = 418
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_AS, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_AS, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_CPU, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_CPU, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_DATA, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_DATA, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_FSIZE, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_FSIZE, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, NULL, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=256, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024*1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, NULL, {rlim_cur=63493, rlim_max=63493}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=63493, rlim_max=63493}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_RSS, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_RSS, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0x402 (flags O_RDWR|O_APPEND)
fcntl(1, F_GETFL)                       = 0x402 (flags O_RDWR|O_APPEND)
fcntl(2, F_GETFL)                       = 0x402 (flags O_RDWR|O_APPEND)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5699248, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 5699248, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2bea149000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3678, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3678, ...}) = 0
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 3678
lseek(3, -2338, SEEK_CUR)               = 1340
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2338
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/etc/sudo.conf", 0x7ffe69316710)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
geteuid()                               = 1000
access("/home/solrevdev/.cargo/bin/sudo", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/solrevdev/.cargo/bin/sudo", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/solrevdev/.local/bin/sudo", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/solrevdev/.cargo/bin/sudo", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/solrevdev/.local/bin/sudo", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/sbin/sudo", X_OK)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/bin/sudo", X_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/sbin/sudo", X_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/bin/sudo", X_OK)           = 0
stat("/usr/bin/sudo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|S_ISUID|0755, st_size=166056, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2996, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2996
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1571, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1571, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2beaa38000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "sudo", 4sudo)                     = 4
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "effective uid is not 0, is /usr/"..., 133effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?) = 133
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

---

Something odd has started happening on my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04

When I open a terminal (either the default one or Terminator) and try to run any sudo command for example `sudo ls` it will hang, then just close/crash the terminal.

It is consistent and survives reboots etc.

It does not even get to the stage where it will ask for password.

However, if I create a test.sh file and run that e.g `./test.sh` then any sudo command will work as expected. It will ask for password then work.

For example, this works:

test.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'sudo will work from here and ask for password and list dir'
echo '----------------------------------------------------------'
echo ''
echo ''

sudo ls
```

But in a terminal window, this crashes:

```bsh
sudo ls
```

I've Googled, and Stack Overflow'd everything I can think of, I've not installed anything new as the laptop hasn't been doing anything for a while.

I've run `strace sudo` which led me to a superuser post which I tried, but that did not work:

```
https://superuser.com/a/1580324

Hold space when booting Pop!_OS
Select Recovery, which brings up the OS installer
SUPER + T to bring up terminal
sudo -i to switch to root
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
Restart Pop!_OS and login normally
Now I am able to run sudo commands such as sudo apt install python3-virtualenv without issues... so far.
```

So before I try anything else, I thought I would ask for some help or assistance as I'm not sure what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated.

OS Info

```
 solrevdev@hplaptop
 OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-91-generic
 Uptime: 11m
 Packages: 3208
 Shell: bash 5.0.17
 Resolution: 1920x1080
 DE: GNOME 3.36.5
 WM: Mutter
 WM Theme: 
 GTK Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
 Icon Theme: Yaru
 Font: Ubuntu 11
 Disk: 148G / 249G (63%)
 CPU: Intel Core i5-7200U @ 4x 3.1GHz [46.0°C]
 GPU: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
 RAM: 3632MiB / 15930MiB
```

Comment: Can you log as root?

Comment: I believe it can be a difference between bash and sh. Probably adding #!/bin/sh instead of bash will break also. Check if thats the problem. Its not a solution but a hint from where it might come from.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/57040/what-is-the-difference-between-su-sudo-bash-and-sudo-sh.

You might have something "broken" in sh but not in bash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Comment: Hello solrevdev. I understand that `sudo ls` unexpectedly closes the terminal session window. Does `sudo date` also trigger this? (I'm trying to determine whether it's `ls` or `sudo` that may be at fault here.) Lastly, please add the result of running `type sudo` to your question (not here in the comments).

Comment: @roaima and Santiago, I have updated my post with your questions. Thanks for taking the time to help, It is very much appreciated.

Comment: @roaima I can't even find it defined anywhere. Unless I am not using ripgrep properly, but it found the markdown file which I used to write/update this post here.

It's so strange. I would almost prefer it if sudo didn't work at all it may be easier to debug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we've [identified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683476/sudo-crashes-terminal-but-works-from-within-a-sh-file?noredirect=1#comment1290907_683476) why `sudo` isn't working properly. It looks like what it's trying to do is to redefine just a solo `sudo` without arguments to mean repeat the last command you've entered, but with `sudo` as a prefix.

Clever idea but broken implementation - the unquoted `$@` *must* be enclosed in double quotes for it to work properly, and to avoid recursion the `sudo` command must be used inside the function rather than the function itself:

```
# Redefine sudo to reuse the last command if no args
sudo() {
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]
    then command sudo "$@"
    else command sudo "${BASH:-bash}" -c "$(history -p '!!')"
    fi
}
```

Now, to find where it's defined is going to be harder. This command would be a good starting point (similar to what I assume is your recursive `grep` but that allows for the space between the function name and the `()` to be optional, as well as excluding irrelevant directories):

```
command sudo find / \( -path '/dev' -o -path '/proc' -o -path '/run' -o -path 'sys' \) -prune -o -type f -exec grep -l 'sudo *()' {} +
```

Once you've found it I would recommend you submit a bug report. (Assuming it works for you, you'd be welcome to suggest the code I've provided as a fix.)

Comment: Thanks so much, I am running that now, but interestingly I forgot to put that in my `test.sh` file and pasted in the terminal and expected it to crash, but it's working.

So in another window  I typed `command sudo ls`  and that works!  So the prefix `command` is another workaround. 

Hopefully I can find the culprit in the result of your `find` command.

Comment: `command sudo` works in my terminal without crashing… at least that saves me having to run everything through a `test.sh` file for now.!

Comment: Thanks very much, I can now happily sudo again in my terminal and will update the post once I've found the culprit. Have a great xmas!